# How to find in a sorted list of dates where a specific date lies in between, in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, date, binary-search

I have a sorted list of dates and I am looking for a way to find where an input date lies within that sorted list, but more specifically the upper bound of it.

E.g. if in the sorted date list positions its `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, and then the input date is in between position 3 and 4, I want the function to return position 4 to me.

Is there a pre-made binary search etc I can use for this? Or would I have to write it myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`bisect.bisect_left()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) or [`bisect.bisect_right()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right) (aliased to `bisect.bisect()`) to find that insertion point. It'll find that point in at most log N steps, using a binary search.

The difference lies in what happens when you give it a `date()` that is in the list itself; `bisect_left()` will give the index of the equal value itself, `bisect_right()` gives the index right after it.

Demo:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> list_of_dates = [
...     date(2015, 1, 15), date(2015, 2, 1), date(2015, 3, 31), 
...     date(2015, 4, 25), date(2015, 5, 23), date(2015, 6, 11)]
>>> bisect.bisect(list_of_dates, date(2015, 4, 30))
4
>>> bisect.bisect(list_of_dates, date(2015, 4, 25))
4
>>> bisect.bisect_left(list_of_dates, date(2015, 4, 25))
3
```